# Dynamics CRM 2011 disable jewel menu item

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I want to disable "Save --> Save & New" menu item in jewel menu. In Customizations.xml file, I added below line. But "Save --> Save & New" menu item is still show in the menu.

```
<HideCustomAction HideActionId="Mscrm.Jewel.SaveMenu.SaveAndNew.HideAction" Location="Mscrm.Jewel.SaveMenu.SaveAndNew"/>
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: I solved my issue using javascript on page load event.

 var jewel = top.document.getElementById("jewelcontainer");
 if(jewel != null) {
        jewel.style.display = 'none';
 }

Comment: DOM manipulations aren't the best way to go for this though, I recommend using [Ribbon Workbench](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx) instead of manually editing `Customizations.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you added that line to the correct DiffXML (and save and published after importing the modified solution)?  You may have done that within one entity, which would cause that one entity's menu to no longer have save and new.  I also usually see the entity name within the location, I don't see it in yours.
Use the [Ribbon Workbench](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx) if you are having issues modifying the ribbon or sitemap or a variety of other 3rd party point-and-click solutions.  Stay away from the DOM as it is unsupported.